# How to generate the terrain of specific area

Tags: unity-game-engine, terrain

I want to create the 3d geographical terrain in unity 3d. I want the landscapes like mountain area, desert area etc type areas in unity 3d which should meet the reality.

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to get the height-map of the area which you want to generate terrain. From that height-map you need to generate the terrain. 
For terrain texturing you have to use the 'Map Puzzle' software and get the terrain texturing by giving the latitude and longitude of the area you chosen, as input. This will create the texture of the area. Import that to unity and apply to terrain(tiling size and terrain size to be same).

Here is my detailed tutorial on the same where you can find the step by step procedure to generate geographical terrains. Follow the below link.
https://u3dtutsbh.blogspot.com/2019/06/building-geographical-terrain-in-unity.html

Comment: Please provide an appropriate answer and not with a link. At least demonstrate
how to solves the answer (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251602/recommending-off-site-resources-when-questions-dont-ask-for-it/251605#251605) in the answer itself.